# Difference between %scan and %lookup in RPGLE?

Tags: lookup, rpgle

If I scan     'NDIA' in 'INDIAN' by using %scan(), a value greater than 0 returned. If I do same using %lookup() in an array then 0 is returned. Why?

**Program 1**

```
D VAR1            s             10a   inz('INDIAN')    
D S1              S             10S 0                  
C     'NDIA'        SCAN      VAR1          S1         
C     S1            DSPLY                              
 /free                                                 
  *inlr = *on;                                         
 /end-free
```

**Program 2**

```
D ARR1            s             10a   DIM(5)       
D S1              S             10S 0              
C                   EVAL      ARR1(1) = 'AMERICA'  
C                   EVAL      ARR1(2) = 'INDIA'    
C                   EVAL      ARR1(3) = 'CHINA'    
 /free                                             
   S1 = %LOOKUP('NDIA':ARR1);                      
   DSPLY S1;                                       
  *inlr = *on;                                     
 /end-free
```

What is difference in both programs?

Comment: You reload arr(1) every time, so the array only has 1 element with a value of 'CHINA'.  Is that a typo in your code or your post?

Comment: Oh sorry...it was my mistake. Now code has been edited so plz reply now...

Comment: The difference is that you use %SCAN() in one example and %LOOKUP() in the other example. They're two different functions that do two different things. Why would you expect them to work the same? You use `NDIA` in your %LOOKUP(), but you didn't load that value in any element of the array. ('NDIA' <> 'INDIA') Since no such element exists, the function returns zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%lookup() looks for an exact match, not a partial match.  If you change your %lookup to look for 'INDIA' it will return a match.

By the way, there is no reason to use the Fixed Format C specs in both of your examples.  They can be entirely /free.

Comment: %LOOKUP() documentation is here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/bbloo.htm%23bbloo  %SCAN() documentation is here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/bbscan.htm